# Existe alguma forma de salvar as edições feitas no inspect element?

Tags: html, google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, dev-tools

Bom, como a pergunta diz, existe alguma forma de eu conseguir salvar localmente no meu navegador as alterações feitas no inspecionar element?. Ou seja para que sempre que vá a tal site, esteja aquilo editado como eu fiz?

O navegador preferencial seria o Google Chrome.

Obrigado.

Comment: nao existe visto que o inspecionar elemento vc edita o html executado pelo seu navegador . o q vc pode fazer é salvar a pagina html offline editada e acessar por ela.

Comment: A ferramenta "Inspect element" é para desenvolvedores da web, para que eles possam inspecionar seu site e fazer alterações em tempo real.Infelizmente você não pode salvar as alterações feitas com o Inspetor de elemento. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim Gonçalo é possível salvar tudo que for feito pelo DevTools do Chrome direto nas suas pastas. Basta que vc adicione o *path* do seu projeto no `WorkSpace` do Chrome e autorize o browser a salvar direto no diretório.

Segue texto parcial retirado direto da documentação oficial do Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=pt-br

**Adicionar arquivos-fonte locais ao espaço de trabalho**

Para tornar editáveis arquivos-fontes de uma pasta local no painel Sources:

1. Clique com o botão direito no painel à esquerda.
2. Selecione **Add Folder to Workspace**.
3. Escolha o local da pasta local que deseja mapear.
4. Clique em **Allow** para dar ao Chrome acesso à pasta.

Adicionar pasta ao espaço de trabalho:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Normalmente, a pasta local contém os arquivos-fonte originais do site que foram usados para preencher o servidor com dados do site. Se você não deseja alterar esses arquivos originais pelo espaço de trabalho, faça uma cópia da pasta e especifique-a como a pasta do espaço de trabalho.

**Organizar mudanças persistidas**

Você já mapeou sua pasta local para o espaço de trabalho, mas o navegador ainda está fornecendo os conteúdos de rede da pasta. Para organizar mudanças persistentes automaticamente no navegador, mapeie os arquivos locais da pasta em um URL:

1. Clique com o botão direito ou segure Ctrl e clique em um arquivo no painel esquerdo de Sources.
2. Escolha **Map to File System Resource**.
3. Selecione o arquivo local no espaço de trabalho persistente.
4. Recarregue a página no Chrome.

Mapear arquivo em URL:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois disso, o Chrome carrega o URL mapeado, exibindo os conteúdos do espaço de trabalho em vez dos conteúdos de rede. Trabalhe diretamente nos arquivos locais sem precisar alternar repetidamente entre o Chrome e um editor externo.

*No link citado acima tem mais informações*