# Como vocês testam posição de elementos na tela?

Tags: css

Utilizo o visual studio 2017 e toda vez que faço alguma alteração em `css` tenho que recarregar a página (e isso leva um tempo), existe alguma maneira de fazer alterações utilizando o visual studio ou até mesmo o navegador para eu testar posições, cores, entre outros sem ter que carregar a página?

Comment: Amigo, eu trabalho com duas telas, então em uma fica a minha IDE e na outra tem o navegador. Só utilizo um plugin de reload pra evitar de eu ficar atualizando várias vezes o navegador. Por exemplo, o Browser-Sync é um deles. O link abaixo que passei pode te ajudar nisso e só precisa fazer o código no VSCode e dar CTRL+5 pra salvar e atualizar automático. Se funcionar para você, não esqueça de dar seu voto lá :D

Comment: Você pode ver essa minha resposta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/347073/existe-algum-editor-ou-ide-que-tenha-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-live-preview-para-php/347084#347084

Comment: Eu criei minha conta ontem, ainda não posso votar, mas assim que liberar eu voto sim, obrigado pela dica

Comment: Claro, sem problemas. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Vc pode usar o Ruby para criar um whatcher que vai monitorar o seu arquivo e no Save ele faz um reload no browser. Mas se vc quisar algo simples o VS Code tem opções bem práticas... Vc precisa de uma solução apenas para o Visual Studio ou pode ser para o Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Para o visual studio, não utilizo visual studio code

Comment: As vezes isso te ajuda então, vc pode salvar direto o seu .css usando o DevTools do Chrome. Assim tudo que vc mudar no inspect do DevTools vc salva no .css/.html! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160767/existe-alguma-forma-de-salvar-as-edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-feitas-no-inspect-element/296826#296826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu, quando estou mexendo com `css` costumo fazer uma pequena parte e inspeciono a página, no google chrome, tecla f12, dessa maneira, vou fazendo alterações que vão me mostrando em tempo real na página, após ficar da maneira que quero, eu copio o que fiz e passo pro meu código, vou mostrar em imagem:

Essa é minha página, quando inspeciono a página apertando f12 eu tenho essa opção em cima para selecionar um elemento na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo após clicar nele e clicar em algum elemento, posso fazer as alterações que eu quiser do lado direito da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ex: alterei a propriedade top e ele já me mostrou automaticamente como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é o seguinte, se eu faço muitas alterações de uma só vez e esqueço de passar pro meu código, eu acabo perdendo o que fiz (sempre que atualiza o navegador, perde as informações alteradas), então eu tento sempre passar, assim que ficou da maneira q eu gostaria

Comment: Jeff vou te dar uma dica e vc nunca mais vai precisar ficar fazendo Ctrl+C/V do inspetor do Chrome. Da uma olhada nessa resposta. Ela ensina como **salvar** as mudanças que vc faz no DevTools direto no seu .CSS sem precisar copiar etc... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160767/existe-alguma-forma-de-salvar-as-edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-feitas-no-inspect-element/296826#296826